# Do these types of wires exist?

Tags: wires, adapter

I was wondering if the following type of wire adapter existed. Because I have some small JST pins and I need to connect them to some JST XH pins. (Preferably on amazon):
[image: JST to JST XH adapter]

JST to JST XH adapter

Comment: JST *What* to JST XH?

Comment: I can do PH to XH custom cables.

Comment: @jsotola Looks like it's been spliced from two images.

Comment: @Majenko you are right ... i was seeing heatshrink tubing ... my apologies to the OP

Comment: @jsotola That's what I thought at first too.

Comment: @DigitalRookie4 what's the application? ... what is preventing you from buying the two different connectors with pigtails and splicing the pigtails?

Comment: @jsotola I am not an expert on all things to do with "splicing the pigtails". In addition to this, the picture was edited and the reason why the wires were different sizes was just because I was just trying to get the idea of what I was wanting across. What I am asking is that do these types of wires exist.

Comment: @Majenko I don't know how to really describe it. A small JST to a large JST?

Comment: Every type of JST connector has a code made from a combination of letters. One end of that is XH. The other end is unknown. You need to know what the JST code is for that end. Then you can google for it.

Comment: @Majenko I have just had a look and I think the small wire is a ZH JST.

Comment: You can buy both XH and ZH cables on eBay. Just get both and connect them together.

Comment: @DigitalRookie4 all you need is some heatshrink tubing, a cigarette lighter and diagonal cutters (or strong fingernails) ... wirestrippers would work, but are more specialized ... strip the two wire ends, twist together, slide on heatshrink tubing and shrink using a cigarette lighter ... no soldering required

Comment: @jsotola I have a soldering kit somewhere (I think). I have not used it before, how about I use that to solder the 2 wires together?

Comment: if you apply solder to the connection, then it becomes brittle and breaks easily, unless the wire does not get moved after installation

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/Master-a-perfect-inline-wire-splice-everytime/

Comment: @jsotola That's perfect! However one wire is quite small in diameter and one is larger in diameter. Will this still work? I have wiring tape which might work instead of "headshrink tubing". Why would I need some sort of lighter to do it?

Comment: Yep sorry, that must have been a typo, you know what I mean. What is the answer to the question above?

Comment: @jsotola I have tried it out with a spare wire and it seemed to work very well

Comment: heatshrink tubing shrinks about 50% in diameter when heated ... a butane cigarette lighter is the easiest tool to use ... electrical tape tends to become gummy and peels off ... heatshrink tubing grips the wire insulation tightly and becomes a good strain relief for the connectionby keeping it together and maintaining flexibility